# Excel VBA run time error 9 Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I used following VBA code to record the data after a particular interval of time.This works fine but when i open another Excel file this  error 9 Subscript out of range occurred.How to fix it so that during the code running i can work in another excel file simultaneously.

```
   Dim NextTime As Double
   Sub RecordData()
   Dim Interval As Double
   Dim cel As Range, Capture As Range
   Interval = 60    'Number of seconds between each recording of data
   Set Capture = Worksheets("Max OI").Range("D34:K34") 'Capture this column of data
   With Worksheets("Record")   'Record the data on this worksheet
   Set cel = .Range("A2")  'First timestamp goes here
   Set cel = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cel.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
   cel.Resize(Capture.Rows.Count).Value = Now

   cel.Offset(0, 1).Resize(Capture.Rows.Count, Capture.Columns.Count).Value = Capture.Value

   End With

   NextTime = Now + Interval / 86400
   Application.OnTime NextTime, "RecordData"
   End Sub

   Sub StopRecordingData()
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.OnTime NextTime, "RecordData", , False
   On Error GoTo 0
   End Sub
```

Comment: Try qualifying the workbook. so use `Set Capture = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Max OI").Range("D34:K34")` and `Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Record")`

Comment: `Worksheets()` by itself (in a regular code module) will always refer to the ActiveWorkbook: that's why you should always by specific about which workbook you want to operate on.